# Default user in django (sentinel value)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a model:

```
class NotificationSettings(models.Model):
    android_device = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.AndroidDevice',
        default=None,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("user", "android_device")
```

My problem is that I have unique_together on fields that are nullable. I learned that in PostgreSQL (and generally in the SQL standard) NULL != NULL, so I can end up with, for example, two NotificationSettings objects that have the same device_id and user is NULL in both cases.

I thought that using `NotificationSettings.objects.get_or_create()` everywhere I create these objects would suffice but I guess there is a race condition when two request are hitting the endpoint in almost the same time, and I end up with duplicates anyway.

This is why I wanted to make this constraint on the PostgreSQL level and was thinking about changing the user field to not being nullable and having default user instead.

But I feel like creating default user might have some kind of security consequences.

So my question is: Is this a good practice (or practice at all) to create such a sentinel/default user object? Are there any caveats/security risks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just stumbled across this in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models

def get_sentinel_user():
    return get_user_model().objects.get_or_create(username='deleted')[0]

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user),
    )
```

So I guess it's OK to have a sentinel users in a DB.